# Get the same pam average Silhouettes using different seeds in R

Tags: r, random, cluster-analysis

For each `k`,  I use different seeds and add each `pam average Silhouette` to `sil` array. the code is like bellow:

```
  sil <- numeric(5)
  for(k in 3:10){
    for (i in 1:5){
      set.seed(i)
      PAM<-pam(RFML_table,k)
      sil[[i]]<-PAM$silinfo$avg.width
    }
    minSil[[k]]<-min(sil)
    maxSeed[[k]]<-which.max(sil)
  }
  kClust<-which.max(minSil)
  kSeed<-maxSeed[kClust]
```

However, each time, my `sil` array's elements are equal. For example, `sil` elements for `k=3` are `0.8695872 0.8695872 0.8695872 0.8695872 0.8695872` . 
    My question is why I get same elements in each `k`. I expect different `sil` elements because `pam` results may be different for each seed and, as a consequence, `average Silhoettes` for `pam`s may be different!

**UPDATE:**

Finally, I test the `iris` data and use both `pam` and `k-means`. here is the code:

```
library(cluster)
dni3 <- dimnames(iris3)
ii <- data.frame(matrix(aperm(iris3, c(1,3,2)), ncol = 4,
                        dimnames = list(NULL, sub(" L.",".Length",
                                                  sub(" W.",".Width", dni3[[2]])))),
                 Species = gl(3, 50, labels = sub("S", "s", sub("V", "v", dni3[[3]]))))
all.equal(ii, iris) # TRUE
ii$Species=NULL
dissE <-daisy(ii)
dE2<- dissE^2
minSil<-numeric(10)
maxSeed<-numeric(10)
sil <- numeric(5)
seeds<-numeric(5)

for(k in 3:10){
  for (i in 1:5){
    set.seed(i*1000)
    PAM<-pam(ii,k)
    sil[[i]]<-PAM$silinfo$avg.width
  }
  s=c(s,sil)
  minSil[[k]]<-min(sil)
  maxSeed[[k]]<-which.max(sil)
}
for(k in 3:10){
  for (i in 1:5){
    set.seed(i*1000)
    km <- kmeans(ii,centers =  k)
    sil[[i]]<-mean(silhouette(km$cl, dissE)[,3])
  }
  z=c(z,sil)
  minSil[[k]]<-min(sil)
  maxSeed[[k]]<-which.max(sil)
}
```

this is the last loop `sil` for `pam`:

`[1] 0.2918482 0.2918482 0.2918482 0.2918482 0.2918482`

this is the last loop `sil` for `k-means`:

`[1] 0.3109128 0.4291905 0.4262538 0.3160188 0.2875212`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PAM ues a rather complex initialization scheme to reduce the number of expensive iterations afterwards. It is much more likely to choose the same initial centroids each time than k-means which just picks k random objects.